# What is the infinite sum of regular numbers?

Tags: summation

What and is the infinite sum of regular numbers? $\sum 1/r$ where r is regular number.
Upto 10 digit accurate. Thanks

Edit. http://oeis.org/A003592

Comment: "regular number" = ?

Comment: @Greg Martin 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 16, 20, 25.....

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003592

Comment: Well, now we have a nice guessing game. Is it the set of integers whose reciprocals have a finite decimal expansion?

Comment: @TonyK yes finite.

Comment: @Waqar, brevity is a virtue. But only up to a point...

Comment: If some such result is known, it would probably be linked at OEIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the question is referring to numbers of the form $2^m 5^n$. In that case,
$$
\sum_{r=2^m5^n} \frac1r = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{2^m5^n} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{2^m} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{5^n} = 2\cdot\frac54 = \frac52.
$$
To 10-digit accuracy, the answer is 2.5000000000.

Comment: No, that is 10-decimal-place accuracy. 10-digit accuracy is 2.500000000.

Comment: "10 digit accuracy".Dammit I can't stop laughing.